# How export animation from Spine to body from Box2D

Tags: c++, animation, box2d, game-engine, spine

I have a problem: I will have animation, created in Spine. Spine can export animation in JSON and atlas file. I found many Spine runtimes for add animations to many game engines, but didn't find for Box2D. Can you help me? Where I can will find this module or exist any solution?

Thank you for your future reply!

Answer (score 0):

Box2D is 2D physics engine. So it doesn't implements any 'animation'.

Comment: Yes, I know. I can not change the animation instead of the figures that are used as the animation of the body parts?